# If additive is "something added", what would be "something subtracted"?

Tags: antonyms

Yes I know I can check the dictionary. But I can't find this part.

Additive is both noun and adjective. The antonym for the adjective usage is *subtractive*, because it's an adjective too. But I can't find a **noun** antonym for the **additive** as a noun.

Comment: Many nouns don't have opposites. What is the opposite of "table"? Perhaps you could describe what sort of item you would expect to be the opposite of an additive.

Comment: Actually I search for a name for anything that might be reduces from anything else. In other words, things like tax, like discount,  like credit, etc. etc. would be categorized in this concept.

Comment: _Additive_ generally refers to food or chemistry, where the antonym is _extract_ or _precipitate._ There are other words used in domains like math (_subtrahend_) and finance (_discount_), but you wouldn't normally use _additive_ in those domains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Additive* usually refers to a chemical compound or foodstuff. A portion removed from such a substance is an [*extract.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extract#Noun) The specific case of a solid removed from a solution is a [*precipitate.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precipitate#Noun)

Tax and finance use a variety of words for subtraction (*discount, deduction, debit, credit*), and the mathematical term is *subtrahend,* but the word *additive* is not usually used in those domains. Likewise, documents and works of art don't usually have additives, but a portion removed from a document is sometimes called an *extract* just like a substance is; *excerpt* is also common.

---

Related [terms used in arithmetic equations](http://www.factmonster.com/ipka/A0881931.html):

- augend + **addend** = sum
- minuend – **subtrahend** = difference
- multiplicand × **multiplier** = product
- dividend ÷ **divisor** = quotient

Augends, addends, minuends, and subtrahends are all collectively called *terms.* Multiplicands, multipliers, dividends, and divisors are all collectively called *factors.*

Comment: Does subtrahend have an antonym? That would be useful for me. A number that is added to another number.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati "Augend" and "addend".

Comment: Nice findings guys. Is there a general term for to encompass both **addend** and **subtrahend**? Something that denotes *base value modifier*?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati [Operand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

English is indeed a very vibrant language. There will not necessarily be an antonym to every noun. Therefore, in a manner of speaking, I would use some of the following expressions to express the idea of "something subtracted".

```
devoid of
in the absence of 
without any (carbohydrates, sugar, fat etc for instance)
```